# Create sub array with key value and sort it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

Given below is an array of objects, need to create sub-array in it with common `make` key, also all sub-array and main array needs to be sorted as follows:

1. the main array to be sorted on `make` key `alphabetically`.
2. sub-arrays to be sorted `ASC` on the basis of the `year`.

Input Array:

```
const cars = [
    {
        "make": "audi",
        "model": "r8",
        "year": "2006"
    }, {
        "make": "audi",
        "model": "s5",
        "year": "2005"
    }, {
        "make": "ford",
        "model": "mustang",
        "year": "2012"
    }, {
        "make": "ford",
        "model": "fusion",
        "year": "2015"
    }, {
        "make": "kia",
        "model": "optima",
        "year": "2012"
    },
];
```

Desired Array:

```
const cars = [
    {
      "make": "audi",
      "list": [
        {
          "model": "s5",
          "year": "2005",
        },
        {
          "model": "r8",
          "year": "2006",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      "make": "ford",
      "list": [
        {
          "model": "mustang",
          "year": "2012",
        },
        {
          "model": "fusion",
          "year": "2015",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      "make": "kia",
      "list": [
        {
          "model": "optima",
          "year": "2012",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

What I have tried yet:

```
let filteredData = [];

cars.forEach((value)=>{

    var foundIndex = filteredData.findIndex( car => car.make === value.make );

    if(foundIndex != -1){

        let carData = filteredData[foundIndex];
        const {list} = carData;
        let nextObj = {'model': value.model, 'year': value.year};
        const newData = [...list, nextObj];
        carData['list'] = newData;
        filteredData[foundIndex] = carData;

     }else{
          
        let values = {'model': value.model, 'year': value.year};    
        let data = [values];
        let obj = {'make':value.make, 'list': data};
        filteredData.push(obj);
     }
});
const sortedCars = filteredData.sort((a, b) => a.make.localeCompare(b.make));
```

Any optimal solution for this to make it better is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a 'group by' with sorting. To avoid having to sort multiple nested arrays in the result you can sort (a copy) of the array by `year` before grouping, and then sort the result by `make` afterwards. Here using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop grouping into an object and then sorting the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) as the result.

```js
const cars = [
    { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2006' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 's5', year: '2005' },
    { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' },
];

const grouped = {};

for (const { make, ...rest } of [...cars].sort((a, b) => a.year - b.year)) {
    (grouped[make] ??= { make, list: [] }).list.push({ ...rest });
}

const result = Object.values(grouped).sort((a, b) =>
    a.make.localeCompare(b.make)
);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, because javascript objects sort integer properties by default you can 'group by' year within each `list` and then map the resulting object values to arrays. The outer array will need to be sorted explicitly.

```js
const cars = [
    { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2006' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 's5', year: '2005' },
    { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' },
];

const result = Object.values(
      cars.reduce((a, { make, year, ...rest }) => {
          a[make] ??= { make, list: {} };
          a[make].list[year] ??= [];
          a[make].list[year].push({ year, ...rest });

          return a;
      }, {}))
    .map(({ make, list }) => ({ make, list: Object.values(list).flat() }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.make.localeCompare(b.make));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredData = [];

cars.forEach((value)=>{

    var foundIndex = filteredData.findIndex( car => car.make === value.make );

    if(foundIndex != -1){

        let carData = filteredData[foundIndex];
        const {list} = carData;
        let nextObj = {'model': value.model, 'year': value.year};
        let newData = [...list, nextObj];
        
        newData.sort((a, b) => a.year.localeCompare(b.year));
        carData['list'] = newData;
        filteredData[foundIndex] = carData;

     }else{
          
        let values = {'model': value.model, 'year': value.year};    
        let data = [values];
        let obj = {'make':value.make, 'list': data};
        filteredData.push(obj);
     }
});
const sortedCars = filteredData.sort((a, b) => a.make.localeCompare(b.make));
```